# Referencing Item to select a sheet when using a dictionary to loop through

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA code so please bear with me.

I need help in setting the item reference when it comes to selecting sheet

How can I make clear in the code that I want to select the sheet based on the key it is iterating through.
For example, when they KEY 200 is chosen it should choose the GSF sheet and only paste values filtered with 200.

```
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
'Add some (key, value) pairs
dict.Add 200, "GSF"
dict.Add 400, "REN"
dict.Add 500, "P&T"
dict.Add 600, "RIG"
dict.Add 800, "O&G"

For Each Key In dict.Keys
ActiveSheet.Range("$H$8:$O$100").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Key
Columns("H:O").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets(dict.Items).Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Calculate").Select
Next

End Sub
```

Right now the result is giving me on all sheet same data from the last iteration with the number 800.
One column in my sheet contains these numbers. I want VBA to paste all the values filtered with 200 into GSF sheet, values filtered with 400 into REN sheet and so on...

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Dim dict As Object
Dim k As Variant

Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dict.Add "GSF",200
dict.Add "REN",400
dict.Add "P&T",500
dict.Add "RIG",600
dict.Add "O&G",800

For Each k In dict.Keys
   'Debug.Print k, dict(k)
   ActiveSheet.Range("$H$8:$O$100").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=dict(k)
   Columns("H:O").Copy
   Sheets(k).Range("A1").Select
   ActiveSheet.Paste
   Sheets("Calculate").Select
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me!

I integrated your changes and I get a error:

Run time error 1004
Select method of Range class failed

Line: Sheets(k).Range("A1").Select

So I switched that line for 2 lines - Sheets(k).Select
     - Range("A1").Select

It works!! I am very grateful to you

Answer (score 0):

Without using ActiveSheet or Select

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub demo()

    Dim dict As Object, k As Variant
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With dict
        .Add "GSF", 200
        .Add "REN", 400
        .Add "P&T", 500
        .Add "RIG", 600
        .Add "O&G", 800
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Sheets("Calculate").Range("H8:O100")
        For Each k In dict.Keys
            .AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=dict(k)
            .Copy Sheets(k).Range("A1")
        Next
        .AutoFilter
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Done"
    
End Sub
```